# How to write the index number in the Wolfram Alpha search engine

Tags: sequences-and-series, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to see some results for my sequence in Wolfram Alpha, but I don't know how to enter the "n" letter as an index. My sequence is a_(n+1) = ((3a_n)+2)/5. The [reddit answer with underscores does not help](https://www.reddit.com/r/wolframalpha/comments/5orwdb/how_do_you_type_subscripts_in_the_wolframalpha/) `a­­­­_(n+1) = (3a_n+2)/5`, neither does the subscript function. `subsrcript[a­­­­, n+1] = (3*subscript[a, n]+2)/`. What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try { and }. Just have a look at : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%C2%AD%C2%AD%C2%AD%C2%AD_%7Bn%2B1%7D+%3D+(3a_%7Bn%7D%2B2)%2F5

Comment: The what is this (   http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) documentation for? It cleary shows the result.

Comment: They make a distinction (and they are right) between a sequence (which they see as a function) and a subscript which is only an indexation.

Comment: Ok, so that is the difference. Thanks.